# Querying user segment data through Google Analytics spreadsheet add-on

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

When accessing GA data through the browser, Google analytics will throw an error if you try to create a user segment on a data range that exceeds 90 days. However, when I do this using Google's own spreadsheet add-on on Google sheets, the data does get generated.

I am trying to query 1 year's of users' data through the spreadsheet add-on. Now I am not sure if this data that was produced is actually measuring what I intended. Does the add-on step over the limitations that were placed on Google Analytics accessed through a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Query builder : https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/